one-off scheduled async task library for Flask
I have a flask server and currently for async tasks i am using celery but according to celery docs it doesn't recommend using celery for scheduling task which to executed far in future.
For eg. Todays date is 9th Dec 2024, 1pm and i want to schedule as task 2 days from today
that is on 11th Dec 2024, 1pm 

But celery doesn't recommend delaying task that much in the future.
So i am looking for a library which can achieve this functionality considering it can handle a load of enterprise level.
